# How to make a file editable by two different users in different groups?

Tags: linux, permissions, ownership, chown

I have a folder at `/home/www/`, and the owner is `www`, which is part of the `www`-group. I have another user, `john`, part of the `john` group. How can I `chown` `/home/www/` to make it writable by both `www` and `john`? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than modify permissions on the directory, it might be easier to put the user john into the `www` group. Users can be in multiple groups. Use either usermod, edit the `/etc/group` file, or if you have a GUI on your linux machine use the graphical user manager program (might be called different names based upon distro and desktop environment). The easiest method is probably to open a command prompt, and type in:

`sudo usermod -G www -a john`

It'll ask for your account password, and once you enter it, the user john will be have group level access to the /home/www directory.

This is assuming the group www already has read/write/execute access to the /home/www directory If that group doesn't have that level of access then use `chgrp www /home/www` and `chmod g+rwx /home/www` to take care of that.

note: if you are currently logged in as 'john', you may need to log out and back in for your permissions to update.

Comment: Or create another group that both www and john are in, if you need finer grained access.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating new group `www-and-john`, then

`chown -R www:www-and-john /home/www/`

`chmod -R g+w .`

and in the end add both users to group `www-and-john`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. But you may be able to set an ACL for it.

```
setfacl -m g:john:rwx /home/www
```

Comment: You will probably need to add `acl` to mount options (either in `fstab` or using `mount -o remount,acl /`).

Comment: Also, don't forget that giving `rwx` for `/home/www` does _not_ give write access to the files inside.